# PDFBox extracting blanks from PDF encrypted with no password

Tags: java, encryption, pdfbox

I'm using PDFBox to extract text from forms and I have a PDF that is not encrypted with a password but PDFBox says is encrypted.  I suspect some sort of Adobe "feature" since when I open it it says (SECURED), while other PDFs that I don't have issues with do not.  `isEncrypted()` returns `true` so despite not having a password it appears to be secured somehow.

I suspect that it is not decrypting properly, as it is able to pull the form's text prompts but not the responses themselves.  In the code below it pulls `Address (Street Name and Number)` and `City` from the sample PDF, but not the response in between them.

I am using PDFBox 2.0, but I have also tried 1.8.

I've tried every method of decrypting that I can find for PDFBox, including the deprecated ones (why not).  I get the same result as not trying to decrypt at all, just the Address and City prompts.

With PDF's being the absolute nightmare that they are, this PDF was likely created in some non-standard way.  Any help in identifying this and getting moving again is appreciated.

[Sample PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0x6wntz936m7hjo/i-9_08-07-09.pdf?dl=0)

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageTree;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.StandardDecryptionMaterial;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripperByArea;
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.List;


class Scratch {

    private static float pwidth;
    private static float pheight;

    private static int widthByPercent(double percent) {
        return (int)Math.round(percent * pwidth);
    }

    private static int heightByPercent(double percent) {
        return (int)Math.round(percent * pheight);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            //Create objects
            File inputStream = new File("ocr/TestDataFiles/i-9_08-07-09.pdf");

            PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(inputStream);

            // Try every decryption method I've found
            if(document.isEncrypted()) {

                // Method 1
                document.decrypt("");

                // Method 2
                document.openProtection(new StandardDecryptionMaterial(""));

                // Method 3
                document.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);

                System.out.println("Removed encryption");
            }

            PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();

            //Get the page with data on it
            PDPageTree allPages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages();
            PDPage page = allPages.get(3);

            pheight = page.getMediaBox().getHeight();
            pwidth = page.getMediaBox().getWidth();

            Rectangle LastName = new Rectangle(widthByPercent(0.02), heightByPercent(0.195), widthByPercent(0.27), heightByPercent(0.1));
            stripper.addRegion("LastName", LastName);
            stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
            stripper.extractRegions(page);
            List<String> regions = stripper.getRegions();

            System.out.println(stripper.getTextForRegion("LastName"));

        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use the Acroform fields instead? `doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm().getField("form1[0].#subform[3].address[0]").getValueAsString()`. To get a list of all fields, see the PrintFields example in the source code download.

Comment: A PDF can be encrypted with two passwords: a *user* password and an *owner* password. When a PDF is encrypted with a *user* password, you can't open the document in a PDF viewer without entering that password. When a PDF is encrypted with an *owner* password only, everyone can open a PDF without that password, but some restrictions may be in place. You can recognize PDFs encrypted with an owner password because they mention "SECURED" in Adobe Reader. You need to find a way to ignore that security similar to using the "unethicalreading" flag in iText.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr YES!  It would appear that my document is using floating annotation, so my issue is not with decrypting but data not being where I think it is.  I'm in an area with awful signal so the 16MB for the source is too much, I'll check when I get home though thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brunos comment explains why the PDF is encrypted even though you do not need to enter a password:

> A PDF can be encrypted with two passwords: a *user* password and an *owner* password. When a PDF is encrypted with a *user* password, you can't open the document in a PDF viewer without entering that password. When a PDF is encrypted with an *owner* password only, everyone can open a PDF without that password, but some restrictions may be in place. You can recognize PDFs encrypted with an owner password because they mention "SECURED" in Adobe Reader.

Your PDF is encrypted using only an owner password, i.e. the user password is empty. Thus, you can decrypt it using the empty password `""` like this in your PDFBox version:

```
document.decrypt("");
```

*(This "method 1", by the way, is exactly the same as your "method 2"*

```
document.openProtection(new StandardDecryptionMaterial(""));
```

*plus some exception wrapping.)*

---

Tilman's comment implies the reason why you don't retrieve the form values: Your code uses the `PDFTextStripperByArea` to do text extraction, but this text extraction only extracts the *fixed page content*, not the content of the *annotations* floating on that page.

The content you want to extract is the content of form fields whose widgets are annotations.

Tilman's proposal

> ```
> doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm().getField("form1[0].#subform[3].address[0]").getValueAsString()
> ```

shows how to extract the value of a form field you know the name of, `"form1[0].#subform[3].address[0]"` in this case. If you don't know the name of the field you want to extract content from, the `PDAcroForm` object returned by `doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm()` has a number of other methods to access field contents.

---

By the way, a field name like `"form1[0].#subform[3].address[0]"` in the **AcroForm** definition indicates yet another specialty of your PDF: It actually contains **two form definitions**, the core PDF *AcroForm* definition and the more independent *XFA* definition. Both describe the same visual form. Such a PDF form is called a *hybrid PDF form*.

The advantage of hybrid forms is that they can be viewed and filled in using PDF tools which only know *AcroForm* forms (which is essentially all software except Adobe's) while PDF tools with XFA support (essentially only Adobe's software) can make use of additional XFA features.

The drawback of hybrid forms is that if they are filled in using a tool without XFA support, only the *AcroForm* information are updated while the XFA information remain as before. Thus, the hybrid document can contain different data for the same field...

Comment: Looks like that was it, @TilmanHausherr was right.  The examples in the source files had everything I needed to get moving again.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);

// Check if the PDF is encrypted.
if (document.isEncrypted()) {
    // Get the document's access permissions.
    AccessPermission accessPermission = document.getCurrentAccessPermission();

    // Check if the document has content extraction restrictions or owner permissions.
    if (!accessPermission.canExtractContent() || accessPermission.isOwnerPermission()) {
        // The PDF is encrypted and has content extraction restrictions or owner permissions.
        // It is not password-protected.
    } else {
        // The PDF is encrypted and does not have content extraction restrictions or owner permissions.
        // It is password-protected.
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).